# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str' )

Tags: python

Here's the code:

```
charge = 0.00
gold = 15.00
black = 0
white = 0
woodType = 20.00
signPrice = 35.00
additionalChars = 4.00 

color = input("Please enter black, white or gold: ")
numChars = int(input("Please enter the number of characters: "))

if numChars <= 5 and color == str("black"):
    numChars = signPrice
    print("The charge for this sign is: $" + str(woodType + numChars) == str(charge))

if numChars <= 5 and color == str("white"):
    numChars = signPrice
    print("The charge for this sign is: $" + str(woodType + numChars) == str(charge))

if numChars > 5 and color == str("white"):
        numChars = str(signPrice * additionalChars)
        print("The charge for this sign is: $" + str(woodType + numChars) == str(charge))

if numChars > 5 and color == str("black"):
        numChars = str(signPrice * additionalChars)
        print("The charge for this sign is: $" + str(woodType + numChars) == str(charge))

if  numChars <= 5 and color == str("gold"):
    numChars = str(signPrice + gold)
    print("The charge for this sign is: $" + str(woodType + numChars) == str(charge))

if numChars > 5 and color == str("gold)"):
    numChars = str(signPrice * additionalChars + gold)
    print("The charge for this sign is: $" + str(woodType + numChars)== str(charge))
```

The error I'm getting is: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

Ideally the goal is to input the the color and number of characters to get the total price output for the sign the user would be trying to "purchase".

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong...

Comment: Why all the `str("black")`? `"black"` is already a `str` literal, the `str()` wrapping is wholly redundant.

Comment: Welcome to SO! As you've probably read in the [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) and in the [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) posts, we won't do your homework for you. Please tell us a little bit more of what you've already tried and your interpretation of the error! Here's the documentation of this error: [Python TypeError docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#TypeError)

Comment: What do you think `numChars = str(signPrice * additionalChars)` is doing? It's definitely not anything sane. Same goes for all the `str()` wrapped `numChars` variable initialization after that line (definitionally, a `str` does not represent a *number* of characters, it's *actual* characters).

Comment: Also, a tip: read your code again and ask yourself what's the type of each variable, e.g. `print(type(numChars))`. The TypeError is telling you that you can't add (`+`) variables of type `float` and `str` together, and you're doing that a few times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has a couple issues:

1. **Mixing Numbers and Words**: When you try to add a number and a word (like "apple" + 5), the computer gets confused. In Python, this is like trying to add a `float` and a `str`. It doesn't work. That's why you got the `TypeError`.
2. **Casting to `str`**: When you put `str()` around a number, you tell the computer to treat the number like a word. But you want to do math with it, so you should keep it as a number.
3. **Equals Sign in `print`**: The `==` is used for checking if things are equal. When you're printing, you want to show things, not check if they're equal. So, instead of `==`, just put the things you want to show inside `print()`.
4. **Color Typos**: You wrote `"gold)"` with an extra bracket. The computer is very picky; it wants things to be exact.
5. **Using `elif`**: It's like saying "else if." If the first thing isn't true, it checks the next one. It's quicker than checking every single `if` statement.

Try this:

```py
charge = 0.00
gold = 15.00
wood_type = 20.00
sign_price = 35.00
additional_chars = 4.00 

color = input("Please enter black, white or gold: ")
num_chars = int(input("Please enter the number of characters: "))

if num_chars <= 5 and color == "black":
    charge = wood_type + sign_price
elif num_chars <= 5 and color == "white":
    charge = wood_type + sign_price
elif num_chars > 5 and color == "white":
    charge = wood_type + sign_price + (num_chars - 5) * additional_chars
elif num_chars > 5 and color == "black":
    charge = wood_type + sign_price + (num_chars - 5) * additional_chars
elif num_chars <= 5 and color == "gold":
    charge = wood_type + sign_price + gold
elif num_chars > 5 and color == "gold":
    charge = wood_type + sign_price + gold + (num_chars - 5) * additional_chars

print(f"The charge for this sign is: ${charge}")
```

Changes:

- Made the `print` statement to use [`f-strings`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings).
- Kept all calculations in floats or integers to avoid type errors.
- Re-wrote variable names to comply with PEP8

---

I'm not sure if you have reached functions in your class, but when you do, you might want to consider an approach like the following:

```
"""beginnerAdri's Sign Price Calculator Tool."""

BASE_PRICE = 35.00
WOOD_TYPE_PRICE = 20.00
ADDITIONAL_CHARS_PRICE = 4.00
GOLD_PRICE = 15.00
MAX_CHARS_IN_BASE_PRICE = 5
COLOR_BLACK = 'black'
COLOR_WHITE = 'white'
COLOR_GOLD = 'gold'
VALID_COLORS = frozenset([COLOR_BLACK, COLOR_WHITE, COLOR_GOLD])


def validate_color_input(prompt: str, valid_colors: frozenset) -> str:
  """Validates the user's color input."""
  while True:
    color = input(prompt).lower()
    if color in valid_colors:
      return color
    print(f'Invalid color. Valid colors: [{", ".join(VALID_COLORS)}]')


def calculate_charge(num_chars: int, color: str, base_price: float,
                     wood_type_price: float, additional_chars_price: float,
                     gold_price: float) -> float:
  """Calculates the total charge for a sign based on various parameters."""
  charge = wood_type_price + base_price
  if num_chars > MAX_CHARS_IN_BASE_PRICE:
    charge += (num_chars - MAX_CHARS_IN_BASE_PRICE) * additional_chars_price
  if color == COLOR_GOLD:
    charge += gold_price
  return charge


def main() -> None:
  color = validate_color_input('Please enter a color: ', VALID_COLORS)
  num_chars = int(input('Please enter the number of characters: '))
  total_charge = calculate_charge(num_chars, color, BASE_PRICE,
                                  WOOD_TYPE_PRICE, ADDITIONAL_CHARS_PRICE,
                                  GOLD_PRICE)
  print(f'The charge for this sign is: ${total_charge:.2f}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

**Example Usage:**

```
Please enter a color: yellow
Invalid color. Valid colors: [white, black, gold]
Please enter a color: black
Please enter the number of characters: 34
The charge for this sign is: $171.00
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but it doesn't really point out **where** OP is making their mistake. I won't submit my own answer because I believe that this one can be improved by talking about the `str(var1 + var2)` situation and end up being the correct answer

Comment: I retract my previous comment!

Comment: Thank you all for your advice! I'm very extremely new to all of this, so I didn't really understand that it was an issue with adding words and numbers!